# Why is a function argument default value (an empty list) static?

Tags: python

Code:

```
def func(a=[]):
    a.append(1)
    print(a)

func()
func()
func()
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

I thought the default value, the list, would be re-assigned every time `func` was called, and the answer would be:

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Comment: There has been a LOT of discussion on this already happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 1):

You say you "thought the default value, the list, would be re-assigned everytime func be called." You thought wrong. If you are learning Python you should work through [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) at some point. Here is [what it says about default arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

> The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when
>   the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or
>   instances of most classes.

Read the tutorial for details.